# Why use MapReduce vs HBase shell filter

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hbase

I need to query data on HBase. My queries look like this:

- Show all books of "authorD".
- How many books of author "authorA" are in the database?

As far as i know you can do this with MapReduce or HBase shell filter. Please correct me if i'am wrong.

My question is: Why would i use MapReduce (programming needed) if i can do the same on the HBase shell (no programming needed) using it's filters?

Thank you for your answers. Have a nice day.

Comment: Please read my answer to understand the necessity of batchclient

Comment: pls feel free to ask queries if you have any...

Comment: if you are okay with answer pls flag-up "accept-as-owner".Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There are 3 ways to get the results from your Hbase.

1) **Shell**  : This is for simple sure data analysis with small volumes of data.
This is for small amount of data and is for Developer analysis. 
If you know your rowkey directly you can get the data quickly

2) **Hbase non batch clients** : For example Java client to connect to Hbase apply filters and get results
This is also for small amount of data.

***Why mapreduce Hbase API***

> What happens if your data is huge and you need to process... in that
>   case, Either your hbase shell will hang and it will become
>   un-responsive or continuous flow of data will be there which will be
>   scrolling.. you cant able to see that and analyze..

3) **Mapreduce (Batch Client)** : For processing huge volume of data. You can use the same filter and scan object which was used in Java Hbase client program... to get the results.

***Advantages/Reason to use Mapreduce with Hbase* :**

- Batch/parllel processing
- At least results will be stored as part-files in HDFS(if you mention hdfs as sink)
- You can aggregate results of for ex: Staging table to another summary table
  just like a ETL pipe line...

> One classic examples of the above explanation is counting number of
>   rows...

***Just think why hbase team has given mapreduce job provision of counting rows even the same can be achieved with Hbase shell...***

**Mapreduce Way :**

$ hbase org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.RowCounter

```
Usage: RowCounter [options] 
    <tablename> [          
        --starttime=[start] 
        --endtime=[end] 
        [--range=[startKey],[endKey]] 
        [<column1> <column2>...]
    ]
```

**Hbase shell Way :**  Through hbase shell as well you can do this by

```
$ count 'hbase table'
```

I hope now you will get an answer :-)

Comment: if you are okay with answer pls flag-up "accept-as-owner".Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Tools are used to solve problems.

If you are good at HBase shell and it's faster, convenient to get the data, HBase shell is suitable. Or you should use MapReduce

Answer (score 0):

it really depends on your application and your design spec. I would need more information but looking at your example, Hbase seems to be a good choice over MapReduce, unless you have  massive data and need batch processing.
You can call hbase shell from within your application but the preferred way is via hbase java client (assuming your are using java). It's extremely easy and very powerful....